# What is the difference between "vergehen" and "aussterben"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

> Ohne Wasser werden die Pflanzen aussterben.
>
> Ohne Wasser werden die Pflanzen vergehen.

Are *aussterben* and *vergehen* interchangeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first sentence doesn't make sense. `aussterben` means `to die out` in the sense a whole species dies out, like for instance

```
Der Orang Utan ist vom Aussterben bedroht.
Der tasmanische Tiger ist ausgestorben.
```

In your second sentence `vergehen` could be used in that context, but I would rather use the word `absterben`, which means `to die off`

```
Ohne Wasser werden die Pflanzen absterben.
```

`vergehen` is usually used with events and time like

```
Die Zeit verging wie im Fluge.
```

Comment: Well, the first sentence is also right, if you want to say that when there's no more water on the earth, plants will die out.

Comment: @PMF You could say that, but then `Ohne Wasser werden alle Pflanzen absterben.` would be more correct idiomatically in that context.

Comment: Hmm... I'd rather say that as `Ohne Wasser wird alles Leben auf der Erde aussterben.` Talking about the worlds end.

Comment: Definitely. No the work's done, let's have a drink at the bar at restaurant at the end of the universe. ;)

Comment: Oh, I heard they served good waiter's legs...

Comment: Regarding *absterben*: That word is not likely to be used in this context. The principal use is for the [dying of parts of something](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/absterben).

Comment: Regarding *vergehen*: The meaning that you refer to is not the one that is relevant here, but the one that is rare now but preserved in *vergänglich*. [See nr 2](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vergehen)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Regarding _absterben_: I disagree. IMHO  _absterben_ works perfectly fine in this context, see Bedeutung 1.b in your link to Duden

Comment: 1b is not about living things.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Regarding _vergehen_: Not sure what you mean exactly. How does _vergänglich_ come into this? _Vergänglich_ does not make any sense in the context of the OP's question.

Comment: @Carsten Schlutz Regarding _absterben_: Where do you have the information, that 1b is not about living things? Have a look at the synonyms as well: "eingehen, verblühen, verdorren, verkümmern, vertrocknen, verwelken". These all work well with dying plants.

Comment: The word *vergehen* does have a meaning of *to die* (see [number 4](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GV01377), which is the one that is relevant to the question and which you do not address. I only mentioned *vergänglich*, because it is derived from *vergehen* in that sense and is more common.

Answer (score 4):

**Aussterben** is simply to **die out**. You wouldn't use it for one single plant in your room in English and it works the same in German.

**Vergehen** means *to pass* (the intransitive version) and it can go in many directions one of which is to **whither away**. You can use it for pain or love and if you want you can also use it for plants (not for animals and humans). That would be a rather high brow use though. The common term for the basil plant on the window sill is *eingehen*.

So botton line... the two words have no overlap and they are never interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "eingehen" for animals or plants in the sense of dying.